# Nbclust function in R: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to perform hierarchical clustering and I want to use nbclust in order to identify the optimal number of clusters. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Error in t(jeu) %*% jeu : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I already produced a dissimilarity matrix and plotted the dendogram. My dataset comprises of 2 numeric variables and 260 observations.

I have tried a couple of solutions suggested in other questions, such asnot including the data in the function and only use the dissimilarity matrix but I get the following error:

> Data matrix is needed. Only frey, mcclain, cindex, sihouette and dunn can be computed.

The code I've been using is the following:

```
dist.gower <- daisy(mydata, metric = "gower")

aggl.clust.c <- hclust(dist.gower, method = "complete")
plot(aggl.clust.c,
     main = "Agglomerative, complete linkages")

NbClust(mydata, diss="dist.gower", method= "complete", index="all")
```

The dendrogram is plotted succesfully, but I keep getting this error message:

> Error in t(jeu) %*% jeu : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Data matrix is needed. Only frey, mcclain, cindex, sihouette and dunn can be computed.

This refers to the *fact* that some indexes (all but the mentioned ones) *require* coordinate data. See the definitions of the indexes!

Since some indexes cannot be computed without coordinates, `index="all"` is not valid the.

Use `index="silhouette"` and the error should go away.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. However, I was wondering if there was a particular reason that I have to exclude a data matrix in order to use the function. Are the results valid if I just include a similarity matrix?